# Sum of two divs widths is greater than parent width. How to make the browser resize the last div instead of moving it to the next line?

Tags: html, css

Here is my example - http://jsfiddle.net/xcSvD/

HTML:

```
<div id="parent" >
  <div id = "child1"></div>
  <div id = "child2"></div>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
    #parent {
        width: 200px;
        height: 30px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        overflow:hidden;


}

    #child1 {
        height:100%;
        width:100px;
        float:left;
        border: 1px solid green;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

     #child2 {
         height:100%;
         overflow:hidden;
         width:95px; 
         /*width:105px;*/
         float:left;
         border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

As you can see, there are two divs, each having style "overflow:hidden".
Case 1: When sum of divs' widths  does not exceed parent's width (100+95 < 200), everything is ok, two divs are rendered close to each other.
Case 2: When sum of divs' widths does exceed parent's width (100+105 > 200), the latest div is moved on the next line.
How can I make it so that the last div in the case 2 would take all the remaining space (200 - 100) instead of moving to the next line?

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for.  If you can control the CSS, why wouldn't you just set child2 to width:95px so everything is ok?

Comment: Could you just re-check your css, because whenever I copy the CSS from your question, and paste it into your fiddle (you forgot to add it there). It works as you would expect it to.

Comment: @MindlessCake uncomment the second width rule.

Comment: @avrahamcool Then I understand your problem I'll post your answer

Comment: @MindlessCake i'm not the OP, I just provided an answer to your question. (and to thw OP's..)

Comment: Ah okay, well mine is slightly different.

Comment: Ok, maybe my question is not clear, because I didn't mention that  #parent could be resized via javascript. One moment parent is 300px width, child 1 (100px) and child 2 (105 pix) all fit into the parent, next moment  the parent is resized (200px) and the second child disappears (ok, we all know it is moved to the second invisible line, but the user doesn't see it)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this  <kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xcSvD/3/)</kbd>, the second div is never wider then 105px, but if the parent is small, the second div spans only to the end.

```
#child2
{
    height:100%;
    max-width: 105px; /*max width of 105px*/
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: auto; /*important*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/xcSvD/2/)

```
#parent {
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#child1 {
    height:100%;
    width:100px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
#child2 {
    height:100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

The first div's flows left, the second div is a regular block elements, so he takes the remaining space.

I removed the `overflow:hidden;` but you can put it back up..

**EDIT:**

In this new [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xcSvD/3/), the second div is never wider then 105px, but if the parent is small, he spans only to the end.

```
#child2
{
    height:100%;
    max-width: 105px; /*max width of 105px*/
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: auto; /*important*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not what I wanted. You haven't specified width of the second child div and it takes all remaining space from the first div. But I actually want it to be exactly 105px if possible. If parent div is too small (as in my example), let the second child take all the remaining space. But when I resize parent, making it wider, let the second child be exactly 105px wide.

Comment: Yes! The new fiddle did the trick! As I understand, you have to specify max-width instead of width and make overflow:auto. Can you please post this solution in a separate answer, so that I could set this separate answer as accepted?

Comment: @Graf I answered it in a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following won't work since you are specifying 95+105+2+2 (the 2 and 2 is the border box)
you either could solve this using a width of 103 and 93 or just use the following tag:

```
Box-sizing: Border-box
```

You could add this to these two child classes, note that this tag is only supported by browsers that use CSS3, but you could fix this using various of javascript plugins.

```
#child1 {
        height:100%;
        width:100px;
        float:left;
        border: 1px solid green;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

     #child2 {
         height:100%;
         overflow:hidden;
         width:105px;
         float:left;
         border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

Comment: border-box is not a solution for my case. It just specifies, should borders and paddings be taken into account or not.

Comment: If I get this correctly, do you want no matter how wide the divs are, them standing next to eachother hidden in the parent div?

So you could basicly do stuff like a horizontall scroll?

For these cases I usually work with position absolute and margins, but it all depends on what you want exactly.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I don't need horizontall scroll, but you get the idea - two child divs are standing next to each other with fixed widths (100 and 105px), no matter what happens with parent, is the parent wide enough or not.

Comment: The way you want it to work won't work. But what you could do, if you know how wide these divs will be, is set the position to absolute, and a margin from left of howmuch space the div(s) on the left would take.